# Minor Upgrades and patches using WIX

Tags: wix, windows-installer

We have an installer (msi) for our application. It has references to third party components, system & application dlls coupled together (in same feature). Now we want to create a msi for only application changes (adding & removing features/components). Major upgrade is not an option since we dont want to uninstall thrid party & system dlls. How to achieve this using minor upgrade? I m new to WIX & not able to find better solution. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance !!!!

Answer (score 2):

I suppose, you should start from understanding what types of upgrades exist and what each means on terms of Windows Installer. [This MSDN section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370579.aspx) is a good start. When you understand it so you can deliberately choose the type of upgrade you need, learn how to do it via WiX. [This tutorial chapter](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/upgrades-and-modularization/) will help you. WiX.chm (installed together with WiX toolset) contains several topics on upgrade as well.

Comment: Thanks Yan for your reply. I have gone through the upgrade types & followed tutorial as well. I understood that minor upgrade and patching will be good for service packs and patches release. The issue is minor upgrade msi will have complete msi which includes third party  components as well. We dont want to ship the complete msi for service packs. Changes for SP releases are huge so it will not qualify for patch upgrade. Major upgrade is not an option because of uninstalling of third party components.